# new username is created instead of getting updated

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I am trying to create a list of employee. I can assign username, password and email to that employee and also can update employee information where I should able to update username, password or email either. I could create an employee and also create the username and password along with update employee info but when changing the username or password or email of the employee a new user is created.

Here is what I have tried

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Employee
        fields = ('name', 'designation', 'section', 'phone_number', 'mobile_number',
                  'email', 'gender', 'role', 'username', 'password', 'avatar',)

def employee(request):
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        office_instance = OfficeSetup.objects.get(owner=request.user)
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.office = office_instance
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=username, password=password, email=email)
        user.save()
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Thank you')
        return redirect('employee-list')
    messages.warning(request, 'Error')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/hrm/employee.html', context)
```

Edit part

```
def edit_employee(request, id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Employee, id=id)
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
        prev_username = employee.username
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        office_instance = OfficeSetup.objects.get(owner=request.user)
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.office = office_instance
        # change username or password or email if admin has done the changes in
        # those field
        try:
            user_instance = User.objects.get(username=prev_username)
            user_instance.username = username
            user_instance.set_password(password)
            user_instance.email = email
            form.save()
            user_instance.save()
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request, "Following User Does Not Exist!")
        except:
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=username, password=password, email=email)
            form.save()
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, "Thank you")
            return redirect('employee-list')
    messages.warning(request, "Error")
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/hrm/employee.html', context)
```

Screenshot is to make the flow or use-case clear

[image]
[image]

UPDATED CODE

```
def edit_employee(request, id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Employee, id=id)
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
        prev_username = employee.username
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        office_instance = OfficeSetup.objects.get(owner=request.user)
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.office = office_instance
        # change username or password or email if admin has done the changes in
        # those field
        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=prev_username)
        if created:
            user.set_password(password)
            user.email = email
            form.save()
            user.save()
            return redirect('employee-list')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.email = email
        form.save()
        user.save()
        return redirect('employee-list')
    messages.warning(request, "Error")
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/hrm/employee.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_or_create` method is made for cases like this. I'd refactor to do something like this:

```
user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username)

if created:
    # Fields to only populated on creation
    user.password = password
    ...etc...

# Fields to update on creation or update
user.email = email
...etc...
user.save()
```

Details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Good luck!

Comment: There is no need to use try except ?

Comment: I don’t believe so in this case.

Comment: I am getting 
IntegrityError at /dashboard/edit-employee/1
null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint error so I wanted to show you code

Comment: Absolutely - you can amend your question by editing it. I'd add a section at the bottom with the new code block. This way, others can see how we worked through the issue. :) That error means you're passing a value of `None` to the email. If you want to be able to have empty emails, you should add `null=True, blank=True` to your email field definition on the model. `null=True` means the database field can be NULL, and `blank=True` means the form field can be left empty by the user. If you want it to be mandatory, we'll have to look at your code.

Comment: Right, I'm saying to add `blank=True, null=True` to the `email` field on the `User` model. Can you show your `User` model as well in your question? We are really close!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159314/discussion-between-milan-and-flipperpa).